# Ado.net Entity Framework debug visualiser

Tags: entity-framework

Does anyone know if there is a debug visualiser for this yet along the same lines and the linq to SQL debug visualiser?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't one that I'm aware of at the moment (hope to be shown otherwise by other answers here), but Julie Lerman has a post ["An extension method for visualizing ObjectStateEntries"](http://www.thedatafarm.com/blog/2008/04/29/AnExtensionMethodForVisualizingObjectStateEntries.aspx) where she walks through creating a debug tool that pops up a WinForm for inspecting the state of entities via their EntityKey.

Not quite a visualizer, but seriously handy when you need to tease apart ObjectStateEntries to debug change tracking scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a visualizer that does what you are looking for I think - [Visualizer](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-to-Entity-Visualizer#close=1)

Answer (score 1):

Here are visualizers for EntityObject, EntityCollection, ObjectQuery and ObjectContext:
http://entityvisualizers.codeplex.com/, both for .NET 3.5 and 4.0.